# What are the advantages of using a MIDI file when performing a DJ set?

Tags: midi, dj, traktor

I started DJing with traktor and was recently introduced to MIDI files but did not get any details as to why I would want to use these types of files when mixing my deep house set as they do not seem to be of any use in traktor. Are there any special softwares for this type of file?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not a DJ but I suspect the advantages of midi in general would still apply. 
Unlike most other popular formats like wav mp3 midi is not really a recording of sounds. It is rather a record of instructions to be interpreted by a device.

As such software as devices are not obligated to simply play back the contents of the files. The attack, decay, pitch, delay and even instrument that renders the sound can be changed in real time.

In that sense midi is more versatile than a simple audio recording, though it generally does not sound as nice as real instruments. For electronic music they can be really handy.

You can take a midi of a popular melody, modify it to sound like different instruments during your set. Really it is another tool to add to your kit that you can use to expand your sound. I you have no skill/taste in general it isn’t going to help/hurt really. But if you know how to use it your palette would expand.

Comment: @Faith the Faithful, Midi is important if you want to compose music on that kind of software, but if you are only going to mix songs and add sound effects and etc you won't really need to touch those, I really recommend you to search a bit more on the subject tho. Also you can make ".mp3 .wma && .ogg" sound different aswell, that's not really the advantage for using midi's, but yes xerotolerant is still right.